# N-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql

Let's consider the following data structure. There are teams of N employees, where each of them has one of four professions (A, B, C or D). Each employee belongs to only one team, and in every team, there are four employees working at a time (one of each profession).

For example:
Team 1 has 10 employees: 1 and 2 have profession A. 3 and 4 have profession B. 5, 6 and 7 have proffesion C. 8, 9 and 10 have profession D. The currently working employees are 1, 3, 5 and 8.

How to model this data structure to fetch the list of all teams with currently working employees and arrays of the substitute employees of each profession. Something like this:

```
teams: [
    team1: {
        currently_working: {
            A: emp1,
            B: emp3,
            C: emp5,
            D: emp8
        },
        substitutes: {
            A: [emp2],
            B: [emp4],
            C: [emp6, emp7],
            D: [emp9, emp10]
        }
    }
]
```

My attempt is to have two tables:

```
Employees:
    emp_id: ID
    profession: enum(A, B, C, D)
    team: team_id

Teams:
    team_id: ID
    currently_working_A: emp_id
    currently_working_B: emp_id
    currently_working_C: emp_id
    currently_working_D: emp_id
```

I have never encountered such 4-to-many design and I'm not sure if this is the way to go.
Alternatively, the employees could have an additional 'currently_working' column, but then there could be potential consistency problems (two employees of the same profession currently working in one team).

My second question is how to write the query to get the above output. The only way I see right now is to join teams and employees tables and loop over the results and modify the data after the query.

Comment: If you need advice on the structure of the database, you must fully and in detail describe the modeled subject area and the processes in it.

Comment: Not everything can be codified in a schema.  It sounds like some of the constraints you describe are best done in client code.

Comment: Can an employee have multiple professions, or be on multiple teams? Can there be more or less than four professions on a team?

Comment: @Charlieface There are up to 4 employees in one team, but can be fewer (e.g. A is missing). One employee always has one profession and belongs to only one team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you could use the following schema, where each `Employee` has an assigned `Team` and `Profession`, and also an `is_current` column.

```
CREATE TABLE Team (
    team_id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Employee (
    emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    profession enum('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') NOT NULL,
    team int REFERENCES Team (team_id) NOT NULL,
    is_current bit NULL,
    UNIQUE (team, profession, is_current)
);
```

Note that `is_current` is nullable, and MySQL ignores nulls for uniqueness, so you would use either `1` or `NULL`. The unique constraint therefore enforces that there can only be one "current" `Employee` per profession and Team.

In other DBMSs you can use a filtered unique index instead:

```
    INDEX ux1 UNIQUE (team, profession, is_current) WHERE (is_current = 1)
```

To query it, it seems you want a JSON result. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL but it looks like `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and/or `GROUP_CONCAT` might be what you are looking for.